# Optimal Binary Search Trees Knuth

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

Knuth, Donald E. (1971), "Optimum binary search trees", Acta Informatica 1 (1): 14–25,[doi:10.1007/BF00264289](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00264289)

Please have a look at this paper, specifically page 18 in which he tries to prove his lemma that $R_{0,n-1} \leq R_{0,n} $ here $R$ refers to the minimal optimal node which will be the root of the binary tree containing elements $a_{0} ... a_{n} $ .

I understood the idea of the proof using induction that for some $k \,  j_{k}=i_{k} $ . Now the next part of the proof is cutting and replacing,I have understood perfectly till there. What i don't understand is how $F''$ weighted path length is equal to weighted path length of $F'$ for all $a_{n}$. Can anyone please give me a hint or a solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

That proof in fact had an error, in exactly the step in the induction that [your answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/128455/4678) asks about. Knuth published an erratum about it the following year.
See Item 2 in [1] (copied below).  See also [2] for a tutorial with a different, correct proof.

[1] [Knuth, D.E. Optimum binary search trees. Acta Informatica 1, 270 (1972)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00288690) (see below).

[2] https://doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(96)00320-9

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking if `jk = ik`, let's denote `jk=ik=m`, then we think of subsequences of `[0,m-1]` and `[m+1,n]`, treat `[m+1,n]` as a standalone tree. And according to the paper, `T` and `T'` will be of same weighted path length if `αn = α`. So let's make a tree of subsequence `[m+1,n]` with last item being `α`, with weighted path length sum being `Tk`. And then replace the right-subtree of `jk/ik` with `Tk` for both `T` and `T'`.

Let's denote the weighted path length sum of `[0, m-1]` of `T` and `T'` being `T0` and `T0'`. Because `jk = ik`, the levels of `T` and `T'` are both k. So`C(T) = T0 + k*Ak + Tk(starting from level k+1); C(T') = T1 + k*Ak + Tk(starting from level k+1)`; And `C(T)` should be equal to `C(T')`. So `T1 = T1'`

Replace right subtree of ik of T with right subtree of jk of T' will yield T'' with same weighted path length as T'.

PS: actually I don't quite know how it proves `j2<=i2, j3<=i3` using induction and left-right symmetry, anyone can help answer that?